# Attribute "mapType" already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported my project from Eclipse to Android Studio. As it is merging all the files, I am getting error :

```
Attribute "mapType" already defined with incompatible format
```

The source of the error is this file:

```
attrs.xml /PTPlayer/res/values line 24 Android AAPT Problem
```

Eclipse Message

[image]